# CSS/HTML using a radio button to activate hyperlink

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Building a site that uses multiple radio buttons that control multiple content divs sliding on and off the screen. Would like the buttons to also activate a new html loaded into the iframe that i use as a background screen.

Reason for this is i have video playing in the iframe to start and would like to replace it with a simple background html doc when some content comes onto the screen. I can make the label for the radio buttons a hyperlink but this requires 2 clicks 1 on the label and 1 on the button.

CSS Section

```
#iframe_Back   {
position:fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
}

html,body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

input {
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
top:-9999px;
}

label {
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
width:100px;
margin-bottom:10px;
height:20px;
background-color:#ccc;
Border:2px solid black;
border-radius:20px;
}

.slider {
position:absolute;
width:400px;
height:100%;
top:0;
right:-400px;
background-color:#ccc;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
transition: all 0.5s;
}

.slider_two {
top:100%;
left:0;
right:0;
width:100%;
}

.slider_three {
top:-100%;
left:20%;
right:0;
width:50%;
}

#one:not(:checked) ~ .slider_two ~ .slider_three, #two:not(:checked) ~ .slider_one ~ .slider_three, #three:not(:checked) ~ .slider_one ~ .slider_two {
-webkit-transition-delay:0.2s;
-moz-transition-delay:0.2s;
transition-delay:0.2s;
}

#one:checked ~ .slider_one {
right:0;
}

#two:checked ~ .slider_two {
top:20%;
}

#three:checked ~ .slider_three {
top:0%;
}
```

HTML Section

```
<iframe src="video.html" id="iframe_back" border=0 name="Background_1"></iframe>

<input type="radio" name="slider" id="one">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="two">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="three">    

<label for="one">slider one</label>
<label for="two">slider two</label>
<label for="three">slider three</label>

<div class="slider slider_one">one</div>
<div class="slider slider_two">two</div>
<div class="slider slider_three">three</div>
```

Looking for a CSS/HTML solution not Jscript

Thanks

Comment: Any specific reasons why you don't want JavaScript?

Comment: I doubt you will be able to do this without javascript. For a start the iframe and host pages will be trated as two seperate entities there is no way I am aware of to link actions between the two with CSS. Even if the video was embeded in the main page you would need javascript to intereact with it.

Comment: Sorry let me clear it up a little i need the radio buttons to load another page to the iframe not modify the currently running video html.

Comment: Again, not something that can be done without javascript. CSS and HTML are not desinged to dynamicaly change the DOM

Comment: hmm guess i will just add a stop video button somewhere that will change the iframe to a static background html.

Comment: Maybe i should just wrap the iframe in another radio button div then i can just control the opacity of it in the same way i move the other divs around.

Comment: Which again more than likely will require javascript. If you're going to do that then you may as well use javascript on the radio buttons. So the question remains, why the aversion to javascript?

Comment: Adjusting the opacity would probably not stop the video, so if there is audio, it will still be heard.

Comment: No audio on the video just want to cover it up so people can read without flashing images behind it.

I don't know jscript and i only end up doing a website every 5-10 years. still trying to remember my CSS/HTML from the last time i did one.

Comment: Seem to work will try it full scale

http://jsfiddle.net/kWQ3c/74/

Comment: Just watch out for browser compatability issues with CSS transitions. For you IE users they will need to be using 10 or better